# JavaScript Does memory leak happens every time function is called

Tags: javascript, performance, memory-leaks

Currently I am attending a JavaScript training where trainer told us that every function you write is a constructor and every time you call it a new object is created.

Consider following code,

```
function Test(){
  Console.log("Test");
}

Test();
Test();
```

So every time I call Test function, will it create a new object every time?

**UPDATE**

According to him following code does not result in memory leak

```
function Test(name){
    this.name = name;
}

var one = new Test("Nicholas");
```

and following code will allocate an extra object and will result in memory leak

```
function createTest(name){
    var t = new Object();
    t.name = name;
    return t;
}

var two = createTest("Nicholas");
```

Comment: There's no memory leak. And not every function is a constructor, it depends on how you call it, ie. using `new`.

Comment: `Test()` is just a plain old function call. No leak.  No object created.

Comment: An object you create and keep a reference to is NOT a memory leak.  It's an object you created and are using - that is not a leak.  It uses some memory, but that's what all objects do when you're using them.  If you  don't keep a reference to the object in some variable, then the garbage collector will clean it up.  Nothing here is a leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> every function you write is a constructor

No that is not true.

> every time you call it a new object is created.

If you are calling your constructor using `new` then yes a new object is craeted. Otherwise it is not always true.

And yes there is no memory leak which happens when you create an object or when you call a function.

Comment: But if every function is not a constructor then how just calling a function results in memory?

Comment: @code13:- `then how just calling a function results in memory?` I didnt get that!

Answer (score 0):

Every function can *act* as a constructor, but a new object is only created if you call it with the [new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) keyword:

```
var t = new Test(); // t is an object of type "Test"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you baffled by the new operator in JavaScript? Wonder what the difference between a function and a constructor is? Or what the heck a prototype is used for?

**WHAT IS A CONSTRUCTOR?**

A constructor is any function which is used as a constructor. The language doesn’t make a distinction. A function can be written to be used as a constructor or to be called as a normal function, or to be used either way.

A constructor is used with the new keyword:

```
var Vehicle = function Vehicle() {
  // ...
}

var vehicle = new Vehicle();
```

WHAT HAPPENS WHEN A CONSTRUCTOR IS CALLED?
When `new Vehicle()` is called, JavaScript does four things:

**It creates a new object.**

**It sets the constructor property of the object to Vehicle.**

**It sets up the object to delegate to Vehicle.prototype.**

**It calls Vehicle() in the context of the new object.**

**The result of new Vehicle() is this new object.**

**1. IT CREATES THE NEW OBJECT.**
This is nothing special, just a fresh,

`new object: {}`.

**2. IT SETS THE CONSTRUCTOR PROPERTY OF THE OBJECT TO VEHICLE.**

This means two things:

```
vehicle.constructor == Vehicle  // true

vehicle instanceof Vehicle      // true
```

This isn’t an ordinary property. It won’t show up if you enumerate the properties of the object. Also, you can try to set constructor, but you’ll just set a normal property on top of this special one. To wit:

```
vehicle;                          // {}

var FuzzyBear = function FuzzyBear() { };
vehicle.constructor = FuzzyBear;

vehicle;                          // { constructor: function FuzzyBear() }
vehicle.constructor == FuzzyBear; // true
vehicle instanceof FuzzyBear      // false
vehicle instanceof Vehicle        // true
```

The underlying, built in constructor property is something you can’t set manually. It can only be set for you, as part of construction with the `new` keyword.

**3. IT SETS UP THE OBJECT TO DELEGATE TO VEHICLE.PROTOTYPE.**

Now it gets interesting.

A function is just a special kind of object, and like any object a function can have properties. Functions automatically get a property called prototype, which is just an empty object. This object gets some special treatment.

When an object is constructed, it **inherits all of the properties of its constructor’s prototype. I know, it’s a brainful**. Here.

```
Vehicle.prototype.wheelCount = 4;
var vehicle = new Vehicle;
vehicle.wheelCount;         // 4
```

**YOU SAID A MOUTHFUL.**
The JavaScript prototype chain is a little different than how most languages work, so it can be tricky understand. It doesn’t make it any easier when JavaScript gets syntax that makes it looks more like other languages, like inheriting Java’s new operator. But if you know what you’re doing, you can do some crazy-cool things with it.